# Stolen Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) credentials

Tags: encryption, rdp, opportunistic-encryption

I would like to know how to guard against **RDP-renting services** such as dedicateexpress.com which rents out stolen corporate laptops credentials. Are there IDS for such events?

Answer (score 1):

Truthfully the best way would to protect yourself from having your credentials stolen is to protect them.

- If you are building a login script make sure the password is not hardcoded into the script.
- Have a strong password against bruteforce
- Change your password every 30 days or so (Windows has a built in reminder that can be turned on)
- Do not share the password with anyone you do not trust
- Keep your system up to date so all vulnerabilities are patched

> Are there IDS for such events?

I was not able to find one but you could use the RDP log file to make sure there is no intrusions (Depending on your windows machine the log system is in different locations. A quick Google search will find you the location)

Comment: One method of NIDS checks for unusual locations of the stolen corporate laptop and/or repeated login attempts or evidences of DoS attacks. However, the transition period between the actual alarm of system intrusions or network intrusion is unknown.